# Remove all documents of a collection at specific time in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

The goal is to remove all old documents of a collection when ever the first new document is inserted on each day. So the collection only keeps daily documents and discards old ones.

The key part here is that the collection needs to keep old documents until `the first new document` on that day. It is also possible that no document will be inserted for few days, so the old ones should be kept.

One possible solution would be to use **pre** or **post** `save middleware`, and comparing the current date with the latest inserted document creation date each time.  But I think it is too much work, and there might be more efficient and better way of doing that.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Clarity:  So if I have 3 docs dated 2020-11-05, the first doc inserted after 2020-11-05 (could be 2020-11-06,07,etc) will remove those three?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti, yes

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that MongoDB has to remove document is TTL (time to live) who it's kind of MongoDB indexes [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/).

But specifically about your case, there is no other way as you mentioned. [Pre save](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) is the function that you can use it in `mongoose`.

Answer (score 0):

This largely boils down to this.

```
var targ = new Date(the new date);
// start TX                                                                      
if(null != db.foo.findOne({d: {$lt:targ}})) {  // look for at least one older...
    db.foo.remove({d: {$lt:targ}}); // ...and remove them all
}
db.foo.insert(newDoc); // insert in any case
// commit
```